# How to create popup images (prefer not plugin)

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create popup image when user hovers to the images. I have the following codes but the enlarge images will disrupt the flow of my layout. I was wondering if there are better way to popup the image without disrupting the layout. Thanks a lot!

```
   $('#image_layout img').live("hover", function(){
          var $this=$(this);

          $(this).animate({width: "30%", height: "30%"}, 'slow');

       })   not working properly.
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use a plugin?

Comment: If you don't want to use a plugin, you need to create a new div positioned outside the flow of the document with `position:absolute`.

Comment: @Blender just want to practice.

Answer (score 2):

you can actually do this just with css on browsers that support it.

```
#image_layout img {
    transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    transition: all 2s;
    -moz-transition: all 2s;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s;
    -o-transition: all 2s;
});

#image_layout img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.3);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    -o-transform: scale(1.3);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
    transition: all 2s;
    -moz-transition: all 2s;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s;
    -o-transition: all 2s;
});
```

Comment: interesting thought. but the pictures got messed up after hover few times. Thanks though.

Comment: play with it. you can do some awesomes with just css

Answer (score 0):

Instead of resizing the image itself, you should display a separate div with the same image, and resize that div+image.

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to make a popout, i would suggest that you have a position:fixed overlay over your website.

You should have a div, which is normally hidden, but only shows when the user presses a picture. The div should be position: fixed or absolute, so that it doesnt flow in your layout, but just displays on top of all other content

```
<html>
<head><tile>My awesome title</title><head>
<body>
    <div id="photoviewer" style="display: none; position:fixed; top: xx; left: xx">
        <!--Your awesome photoviewer here -->
    </div>
    <!-- The rest of the content of your website here :) -->
</body>
</html>
```

And then use JQuery to show and unshow the div "photoviewer"

Edit: This would work if you wanted to make a photoviewer, but with some javascript/jquery magic you can also make the hover you wanted to have :), then the position parameter should be set to absolute, i guess.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use css, use position absolute and margins that should stop it disrupting the layout.

```
#image_layout img {
    position:absolute;
    margin:_ _ _ _;
}
```

Comment: I don't believe setting a `margin` will stop the layout from getting disrupted. Setting `position: absolute` will remove the element from the flow of the document, so the `margin` will have no effect.

Comment: I think I've misunderstood your original suggestion. If you're going to use `margin` to position an element with `position: absolute`, why not use `top`, `left`, `right`, and/or `bottom` instead since that's what they were intended to be used for? There's still the issue of the absolutely-positioned element being removed from the document flow though. The OP would need a placeholder element to keep the space where the `img` used to be free so that the `position: absolute` image does not overlap anything. This would also make fluid layouts difficult without extra JS.